# ScrollView Not Working(It's Not Scrolling the layout)

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am new to Android and working on a App and stuck here on ScrollView. I have tried width and height "match parent" but still not working. I am posting my code. I have wasted more than an hour on this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.02"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Marketing"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_header"
    android:layout_weight="0.02"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Register Here"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_register"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name*"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Email*"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_pswd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Password*"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_cnfrm_pswd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Confirm Password*"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_forgot_pswd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Forgot/Reset Password"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_google"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GOOGLE"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FACEBOOK"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/fb_blue"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `weightSum` attribute from `parent view` and give `android:layout_weight="0"` instead of  `android:layout_weight="0.04"` in both the `linearlayout` and add `android:layout_weight="0"` to `scrollLayout` also.

Comment: Does this layout works fine except for the scroll issue? coz I can see android:layout_below="@+id/linear_header" in an unlikely place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set lay out weight to scroll view like

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="0.96"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```